# Custom Error Reporting Capability in Django

Tags: django, django-errors

I have setup the ADMINS variable in settings.py. I've configured my email and everything works as intended. I get a very good, detailed error message from my production box when it encounters an error. I also understand the MANAGERS variable and how it can handle 404 errors and send alerts. OK, fine...
However, I have another use case whereas I'd like to send the error report (standard 500 detailed report) to a set of individuals based on the app the error occurs in (or a default if outside a specific app). So, let's say I have 1 person developing/supporting webapp1 and 2 supporting webapp2. If the error occurs in webapp2, I only want to send to those 2 and if in webapp1 the person developing/supporting that app. If the error doesn't occur in a specific app, I'd send to everyone defined in ADMINS variable.

First off, is there a better way to address this use-case than through custom error process?
and..
Secondly, is this possible within the custom error capability?

Answer (score 1):

Django uses [Python's Standard Logging Module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/); probably should implicitly answer how they implement customized
logging behavior. Python has excellent logging [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), [cookbooks](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook), and [how-tos](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

### **Q. How to send application-specific logs only to its maintainers?**

The example below won't go into the specifics of Loggers, LogRecords, Formatters, Handlers, or Django's logging behavior.
`LogRecords` are are propagated to their parent directory. Developer `i.e` **`__author__`** maintaining **`__package__`**
needs to write a `project_level` logger on the `settings.py` file. Assuming `tutorial` is the package a developer is maintaining.

```
.
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── tutorial
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

1 directory, 7 files
```

Focusing on the handlers, django's loggers, and maybe filters for brevity.

```py
├── settings.py

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        """
        another alternate handler inside your package.
        Where custom behavior is implemented. key, value pair 
        dictionary is given. Option to pass extra parameter is the 
        handler class needs one. """ 
                                     
        
        |. # the logRecords will propapagte up
        |. #  to it's parent dirs. Your 
        |. # project root where you'll handle it.
        |...project/
        |... __init__.py
        |... logging.py
        |...    class NinjalFilter:
        |...        raise NotImplementedError

        
        'Ninja': {                                                                                  
            '()': 'project.logging.NinjalFilter',                                      
            'key': 'value',
        },
    },
    'handler': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',  # 4XX (ERROR) or 5XX (Warning) Your Wish
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['Ninja']
        },
    },
    'logger': { 
        """
        Django introduced loggers classes Not in the standard Library. 
        https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#default-logging-configuration
        """
        'YouCustomLogger': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'NinjaProjectMaintainerAdmins'],
            'level': 'INFO', # Again 4XX (ERROR) or 5XX (Warning) Your Wish
            'filters': ['Ninja']
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomNinjaLogger` which seems to be passing your special `Ninja` Filtered LogRecords To handlers `main_admins` and Custom   `NinjaProjectMaintainerAdminsHandler`. Note you might not need the custom `handler`, `NinjaProjectMaintainerAdminHandler`, if `builtin` `mail_admins` does the job.

---

I'm working on an open-source async logger -- which makes logging easier. I could use feature requests, suggestions. Have a good day. Hope The answer helped.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you link to the info page for your logger?

Comment: Do you mean the open-source project? I'm gathering specifications suggestions. It's not even in the alpha phase. Once it's ready, I'd be happy to; if you have more queries do let me know.

Comment: @Eric, we need feedback and testers. If you are interested and you need an easy-to-use logger for Django. Of course, the project will have docs and close support if you use the package. It could help us both. It's an open-source tool with MIT LICENSE. Think it over. and mail me <mail at saadman dot dev>

Comment: I am unsure the level to which i can commit, but I would like to help test. Currently, i have a lot on my plate, but I will contribute as able. :)